# Deploying NextJS Site To Gh-Pages Doesn't Work Even With basePath and assetPrefix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, web-deployment, github-pages

I have a site build with next.js that works locally (code: https://github.com/xpress-smoke-shop/website).

I am trying to deploy a static html version of the site to the domain: https://xpress-smoke-shop.github.io/website/

I can clone the repo and run these commands:

```
nvm use
yarn install
yarn build
yarn export
yarn deploy-gh
```

And I have changed the `next.config.js` file to reflect the repository that I'm using:

```js
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  poweredByHeader: false,
  trailingSlash: true,
  basePath: '/website',
  assetPrefix: '/website/',
  reactStrictMode: true,
});
```

But my deployed site still looks wrong and has all these file-not-found errors...

[image]

Comment: welp, guess it's just me here